# Merging more than one Config files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have the following config files in my C:\Configs directory

1. app.enviroment.config
2. app.dev.config
3. app.production.config

**app.environment.config** just contains this *dev* which can be change from dev to production depending on which config file I want to merge with the main App.config at runtime. How do I make this merge happen, that's either merging from app.dev.config or app.production.config base on the value is picks from *dev*. A sample code will be much appreciated.

I am taking this approach because we have quite a lot of developers working on the same project and I don't want anyone stepping on each others toes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the extension called SlowCheetah http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/

Please have a look at Scott Hanselmans blog how to do the transformation using SlowCheetah http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx